# login forum not showing

Tags: php, html, authentication, forum

I have a site which should have a forum were you login. Unfortunately it is not appearing. There are 2 files: `index.php` and the other is `connect.php`. I have tried taking away the php code from the `index.php` which should see if the username and password mashed what is on the database and shows a message based on that. The forum then appeared. I then added it back and it disappeared. I don't have any idea whats happening please help assist me.

**index.php:**

```php
<?php
session_start();
    if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
        echo $msg;
    }
    ?>

<div class="register-form">
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p><label>User Name : </label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /></p>

     <p><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
     <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></p>

    <a class="btn" href="register.php">Signup</a>
    <input class="btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>

<?php
  //Start the Session

 require('connect.php');
//3. If the form is submitted or not.
//3.1 If the form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
//3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
//3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}else{
//3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
}
//3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "Hai " . $username . "
";
echo "This is the Members Area
";
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

}else{
//3.2 When the user visits the page first time, simple login form will be displayed.
?>
```

**connect.php:**

```php
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('test');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed a } at the last line just before ?> 
Change :

```
}else{
    //3.2 When the user visits the page first time, simple login form will be displayed.
?>
```

Into this :

```
}else{
    //3.2 When the user visits the page first time, simple login form will be displayed.
}
?>
```

Comment: wow this actually worked :)